# OOP design around abstract classes

Tags: java, oop

Lets say I have a `Namespace` class like follows:

```
abstract class Namespace {
   protected prefix;
   protected Map<String, String> tags;

   public setTag(String tagKey, String tagValue) {
      tags.put(tagKey, tagValue);
   }
}
```

I have been told that a good design is to have separate implementations of each namespace with getters defining the information being retrieved from the `tags` map. ie.

```
class FooNamespace extends Namespace {
   public String getNameTag() {
      return tags.get("name");
   }
}
```

We can have separate implementations of a namespace like `BarNamespace` which will have different tags stored (`BarNamespace` does not have a name tag for ex. and instead has an age tag). Why does the above design make more sense than simply having the consumer of a simple `Namespace` class request the tag they want. ie:

```
 class Namespace {
       private prefix;
       private Map<String, String> tags;

       public String getTag(String key) {
          return tags.get(key);
       }
    }
```

The above is used like

```
Namespace.getTag("name");
```

Comment: The answer depends a lot on what you wish to achieve - but if I have to type `getTag("name")` a few hundred times, I'm bound to, 1: Hate you and 2: Make a mistake.  `getNameTag` takes out some of the guess work and reduces the possibility that I'll type `"name"` wrong without noticing. Is it a "good design" is a matter of opinion and is dependent on how the intended class is to be used.  Is `"name"` common enough in the application to be useful?  What about "date" or "numeric" values - some helper methods there might be nice ;)

Comment: The one thing that bugs me about this is that while Bar does not have an accessor for "name", its backed by an abstract Namespace class that contains a raw Map<String, String> so anyone can shove in a "name" tag by doing a Bar.putTag("name", "nameValue"); Any ideas on how to implement the "setters"?

Comment: 1. Make the fields `private` instead of `protected`; 2. Define an `interface` of `Namespace` which provides a non-mutable view and a `MutableNamespace` `interface` which provides mutable functionality.  Expose only the `interface` to those parts of the app which need it

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can you give a small example as an answer for me to fully understand?

Comment: "*separate implementations of each namespace with getters defining the information being retrieved from the "tags" map*" - **From an OOP perspective**, [using getters *not* good design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358611/is-encapsulation-still-one-of-the-elephants-oop-stands-on). Violates OOP, where objects expose behaviors & encapsulate their potential properties (getters are not behaviors - *why* are you "getting"? THATS the behavior). You arent being concrete enough (`foo-bar` example doesn't express the problem - this is XY). What are your actual requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends a lot on what you wish to achieve - but if I have to type `getTag("name")` a few hundred times, I'm bound to make a mistake.

`getNameTag` takes out some of the guess work and reduces the possibility that I'll type `"name"` wrong without noticing. It also reduces the amount of knowledge I need to have about the API - I know I can get the value for the `name` tag, but I don't need to know how that is actually implemented - and it might change between implementations.

Is it a "good design" is a matter of opinion and is dependent on how the intended class is to be used. Is "name" common enough in the application to be useful? What about "date" or "numeric" values - some helper methods there might be nice ;)

> The one thing that bugs me about this is that while Bar does not have an accessor for "name", its backed by an abstract Namespace class that contains a raw Map so anyone can shove in a "name" tag by doing a Bar.putTag("name", "nameValue"); Any ideas on how to implement the "setters"?

This is also a bug-bear I have to the collections API generally.

You could create a non-mutable and mutable concepts...

```
public interface Namespace {
    public String getTag(String key);
}

public interface MutableNamespace extends Namespace {
    public void setTag(String key, String value);
}
```

Then you can begin to abstract those...

```
public abstract class AbstractNamespace implements MutableNamespace {
    private prefix;
    private Map<String, String> tags;

    public setTag(String tagKey, String tagValue) {
        tags.put(tagKey, tagValue);
    }

    public String getTag(String key) {
        return tags.get(key);
    }
}
```

And finally provide useful implementations for the context that it might be used in...

```
public interface MySuperHelpfulNamespace extends Namespace {
    public String getNameTag();
}

public class DefaultMySuperHelpfulNamespace extends AbstractNamespace  implements MySuperHelpfulNamespace {
    public String getNameTag() {
        return tags.get("name");
    }
}
```

Then write you app to support them...

```
public void someMethodWhichDoesNotNeedToChangeTheValues(MySuperHelpfulNamespace namespace) {
    //...
}

public void someMethodWhichDoesNeedToChangeTheValues(MutableNamespace namespace) {
    //...
}
```

This is essentially an example of "coding to interface (not implementation)

Answer (score 0):

## The problem stems from..

Your attempt to reuse `Namespace` via inheritance for it's property: the `Map`.

---

## The idea behind object orientation is to..

Tell objects to perform behaviors.

> <sup>[What is an Object?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html)</sup>
>
> Hiding internal state and requiring all interaction to be performed through an object's methods is known as data encapsulation — a fundamental principle of object-oriented programming.
>
> [image: Object]

When `ClassA` extends `ClassB`, the subtype `ClassA` should inherit the *behaviors*, or the public interface, of it's supertype `ClassB`. **Your `Namespace` type doesn't seem to define any behaviors.**

---

## You may consider the `setter` or `getter` to be behaviors,

But don't be fooled. There is currently no reason for a developer to prefer your `Namespace` type over just using a `Map`, other than changing the interface they use from `get` to `getTag`.

`getter` & `setter` methods violate OOP. Feel free to [read up on the discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358611/is-encapsulation-still-one-of-the-elephants-oop-stands-on).

---

***How* should `Namespace` actually be used**? What requirement is it fufilling? What behaviors should `Namespace` define?

**You can answer this by analyzing how the `getter` is being used**. To give an example, maybe you plan to append it to a `StringBuilder` to conjure some XML.

**Imagine your requirement was..**

> Append an individual tag from a variety of XML tag sets to a StringBuilder that'll be used for rendering.

**Instead of doing..**

```
StringBuilder builder = ...;
Namespace namespace = ...;

builder.append(namespace.getTag("name"));
```

**`Namespace` could be responsible for appending *it's* tags** (`Namespace` is the owner of the `Map` storing the tags) to whatever is requesting it.

```
public final class Namespace {
    private final Map<String, String> tags;

    public Namespace(Map<String, String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    // if you REALLY need to add tags after instantiation
    public Namespace addTag(String key, String value) {
        Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<>(this.tags);
        tags.put(key, value);
        return new Namespace(tags);
    }
    
    // the behavior that fufills the requirement
    public void appendTo(StringBuilder builder, String key) {
        builder.append(tags.get(key));
    }
}
```

**Notice how `Namespace` has behavior** (appends to a `StringBuilder`) rather than act as a proxy for `Map`.

```
StringBuilder builder = ...;
Namespace namespace = ...;

namespace.appendTo(builder, "name");
```

**I'm not looking for reasons to create subtypes (not forcing it)**. You should only create subtypes when you must extend upon the behavior of the supertype. If `BarNamespace` doesn't add any functionality to `Namespace`, there's no need for it.

After creating `Namespace` to cover the functionality your post exposes, I had no need for subtypes. It seemed as if everything was elegantly handled by `Namespace`.

You didn't specify your requirements, but hopefully this answer will guide you towards determining them (based on how you're using the `getter`) and implementing them in an object oriented manner.

---

As @MadProgrammer pointed out:

> if I have to type getTag("name") a few hundred times, I'm bound to make a mistake.

If you find yourself needing to type `"name"` quite often, then you may wanna include a type-safe way for performing that behavior.

In a situation like this, you could prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Instead of having subtypes extend `Namespace`, you could create types that reference a `Namespace` to perform what you want to do.

```
public final class Bar {
    private final Namespace namespace;

    public Bar(Namespace namespace) {
        this.namespace = namespace;
    }

    public void appendNameTo(StringBuilder builder) {
        namespace.appendTo(builder, "name");
    }
}
```

You may say "*Wait! I wanna pass `Bar` to where a `Namespace` is expected!*"

This would be pointless. If code relies on `Namespace`, there would be no type safety to be expected, even in your code. For example:

```
void doSomething(Namespace namespace) {

 }
```

Unless you casted or declares `appendNameTo` to `Namespace`, you wouldn't have access to any methods defined in `Bar` anyways. You said subtypes may have different tags. This means if you're going for type safety, your subtypes would all have different public interfaces, hence why I didn't extend `Namespace`.